# Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want my body to stop scrolling when using the mousewheel while the Modal (from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) on my website is opened.

I've tried to call the piece of javascript below when the modal is opened but without success

```
$(window).scroll(function() { return false; });
```

AND

```
$(window).live('scroll', function() { return false; });
```

Please note our website dropped support for IE6, IE7+ needs to be compatible though.

Answer (score 540, accepted):

Bootstrap's `modal` automatically adds the class `modal-open` to the body when a modal dialog is shown and removes it when the dialog is hidden. You can therefore add the following to your CSS:

```css
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You could argue that the code above belongs to the Bootstrap CSS code base, but this is an easy fix to add it to your site.

**Update 8th feb, 2013**
This has now stopped working in Twitter Bootstrap v. 2.3.0 -- they no longer add the `modal-open` class to the body.

A workaround would be to add the class to the body when the modal is about to be shown, and remove it when the modal is closed:

```js
$("#myModal").on("show", function () {
  $("body").addClass("modal-open");
}).on("hidden", function () {
  $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
});
```

**Update 11th march, 2013**
Looks like the `modal-open` class will return in Bootstrap 3.0, explicitly for the purpose of preventing the scroll:

> Reintroduces .modal-open on the body (so we can nuke the scroll there)

See this: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6342 - look at the **Modal** section.

Comment: this does not work anymore in bootstrap 2.2.2. Hopefully .modal-open will come back in the future... https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5719

Comment: @ppetrid I don't expect it to return. Based on this writing: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Upcoming-3.0-changes (look at the bottom). Quote: _"No more inner modal scrolling. Instead, modals will grow to house their content and the page scroll to house the modal."_

Comment: @MartinHN yeah i know, today the bootstrap team closed the github issue as 'wontfix'.

Comment: And the `modal-open` class will be back to prevent scrolling in Bootstrap 3.0! See my update.

Comment: @anand at the time the current answer was the best answer, after an x amount of time Icannot change the answer anymore.

Comment: Worked for me. Just used `$('body').addClass('modal-open')` before `$('#modal').modal('show')` and `$('body').removeClass('modal-open')` before `$('#modal').modal('hide')`. I have put the CSS code too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bagata Cool - the `modal-open` will return in Bootstrap 3, so when that launches it should be safe to remove the above code.

Comment: This is why one should keep scrolling down, if the chosen answer doesn't satisfy you, there are chances that you are gonna find gems like these. didnt expect a 97+ voted answer burried so deep under other less liked comments.

Comment: Hi @wardha-Web It is only under the accepted answer, as far as I see it. The ranking must be by answer, then by votes. But yes, accepted answers are not always the best :)

Comment: anyway to stop the page from shifting to the right when a modal is open?

Comment: @waspinator You can use the `modal-open` class on the `body` tag again, and set `padding-right: 17px;` - but this is not safe. It shifts the width of the scrollbar which will vary for browser/OS. Also, if the page does not have scroll bars before opening the modal, the padding should not be added.

Comment: @waspinator - I just solved the shifting issue (which is IMO very annoying) with the following CSS code:
`body { padding-top: 70px; overflow-y: scroll; }`
`body.modal-open { overflow-y: scroll; }`
`.modal { overflow: auto; }` ... With this the vertical scrolls will be always visible on body, and the modal scroll will be visible only when needed.

Comment: Chrome for Android just didn't like this solution! I had to go with position fixed, as [Brad outlined below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24727206/945370). YMMV, of course :)

Comment: For some reason pinterest modal dialog is not scrolled. And they use `noScroll{overflow:hidden;}`  on the body and body has `position:relative`  that is never changed to fixed.

Comment: the problem with this is that to prevent the document from scrolling to the top when a modal is opened you needed to add body.modal-open{overflow:visible}. Your solution works at the moment, with the downside that the document scrolls to the top once a modal is openen

Comment: @patrick With 3.0 and newer, it all works as it should out of the box. No need to manually add the `modal-open` class to the body. It keeps the scroll position of body.

Comment: @MartinHN, no, it doesn't... that's why I was looking here for a solution. Might be a combination with something else, but the standard modal caused the original page to scroll to the top once a modal was opened

Comment: @MartinHN Unfortunately not worked for me with Bootstrap 3. On the other hand normally I use `html { overflow-y: scroll; }` on my page body and when modal is open the scrollbar gets twice. Any idea?

Comment: It prevents from scrolling, but cannot stop the scroll events firing. Checked in Mac OS X Chrome version 49.

Comment: Although the background is keep scrolling to the bottom, I make it scroll to the top after closing the modal by using JQuery. 
```$(window).scrollTop(0);```

Comment: Nice one, now I know how to use Inspect Element to get rid of these paywall modals on news sites and make scrolling working again :) Cheers

Answer (score 144):

The accepted answer doesn't work on mobile (iOS 7 w/ Safari 7, at least) and I don't want MOAR JavaScript running on my site when CSS will do.

This CSS will prevent the background page from scrolling under the modal:

```css
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

However, it also has a slight side-affect of essentially scrolling to the top. `position:absolute` resolves this but, re-introduces the ability to scroll on mobile.

If you know your viewport ([my plugin for adding viewport to the `<body>`](https://github.com/will-e-yams/yams.viewport)) you can just add a css toggle for the `position`.

```css
body.modal-open {
    /* block scroll for mobile; */
    /* causes underlying page to jump to top; */
    /* prevents scrolling on all screens */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
body.viewport-lg {
    /* block scroll for desktop; */
    /* will not jump to top; */
    /* will not prevent scroll on mobile */
    position: absolute; 
}
```

---

I also add this to prevent the underlying page from jumping left/right when showing/hiding modals.

```css
body {
    /* STOP MOVING AROUND! */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

[this answer is a x-post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24727026/444382)

Comment: Thanks! Mobiles (at least iOS and Android native browser) were giving me a headache and wouldn't work without the `position: fixed` on the body.

Comment: Thanks for also including the code for preventing the page from jumping left/right when showing/hiding modals. This was extremely useful and I verified it fixes an issue I was having on Safari on an iPhone 5c running iOS 9.2.1.

Comment: In order to fix scrolling to top, you can record position before adding the class, then after class is removed, do window.scroll to recorded position. This is how I fixed it for myself: http://pastebin.com/Vpsz07zd.

Comment: Though I feel this would only fit very basic needs, it was a useful fix. Thanks.

Comment: Here's how I did it to retain the scroll position with jquery:
```js

    const currPageScrollPos = $(window).scrollTop()
    $("body").removeClass("show_overlay")
    $(window).delay(5).scrollTop(currPageScrollPos)
```

Answer (score 39):

Simply hide the body overflow and it makes body not scrolling. When you hide the modal, revert it to automatic.

Here is the code:

```
$('#adminModal').modal().on('shown', function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}).on('hidden', function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
})
```

Answer (score 25):

You need to go beyond @charlietfl's answer and account for scrollbars, otherwise you may see a document reflow.

#### Opening the modal:

1. Record the `body` width
2. Set `body` overflow to `hidden`
3. Explicitly set the body width to what it was in step 1.

   ```
   var $body = $(document.body);
   var oldWidth = $body.innerWidth();
   $body.css("overflow", "hidden");
   $body.width(oldWidth);
   ```

#### Closing the modal:

1. Set `body` overflow to `auto`
2. Set `body` width to `auto`

   ```
   var $body = $(document.body);
   $body.css("overflow", "auto");
   $body.width("auto");
   ```

Inspired by: http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/minute/calculate-scrollbar-width.php

Comment: I was getting a "jumpy" screen for lack of a better term and the key here for me was following the width settings. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Hcabnettek Yep: "jumpy" == "document reflow". Glad it helped you! :-)

Comment: is there a css solution for this? does it work in all browsers and mobile?

Comment: just a typo: It must be `$body.css("overflow", "auto");` in the last step :)

Comment: Oh man, what an marvelous idea. @jpap you helped me resolve the document reflow issue that was bugging me for a long time.

Answer (score 21):

You could try setting body size to window size with overflow: hidden when modal is open

Comment: doing so would move the screen every time the modal is opened, that is not convenient, I just need to disable the background scroll

Comment: not sure that you can scrollbars are browser related and you can't do much with them

Comment: you could set modal to "fixed" so won't move when scrolling

Comment: its not about stopping the modal from scrolling, its about stopping the body in the background from scrolling

Comment: it's the window that scrolls if body overflows it. For example the scrollbars are not part of document.

Comment: your initial answer, I just didn't realize it at the time

Comment: Great solution; you just need to account for scrollbars to avoid a document reflow and content "jump". See my answer.

Answer (score 18):

***Warning:** The option below is not relevant to Bootstrap v3.0.x, as scrolling in those versions has been explicitly confined to the modal itself.  If you disable wheel events you may inadvertently prevent some users from viewing the content in modals that have heights greater than the viewport height.*

---

### Yet Another Option: Wheel Events

The **scroll** event is not cancelable.  However it is possible to cancel the [**mousewheel**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel) and [**wheel**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/wheel?redirect=no) events.  The big caveat is that not all legacy browsers support them, Mozilla only recently adding support for the latter in Gecko 17.0.  I don't know the full spread, but IE6+ and Chrome do support them.

Here's how to leverage them:

```
$('#myModal')
  .on('shown', function () {
    $('body').on('wheel.modal mousewheel.modal', function () {
      return false;
    });
  })
  .on('hidden', function () {
    $('body').off('wheel.modal mousewheel.modal');
  });
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/qrKWq/)

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work on Firefox 24, Chrome 24 nor on IE9.

Comment: @AxeEffect should be working now. The only issue was that the external references to the Bootstrap library had changed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This doesn't prevent touch devices from scrolling, the `overflow:hidden` is better for now.

Comment: they are all working but not for mobile devices. -__- Tested Android 4.1 and Chrome

Comment: @TowerJimmy you probably need to cancel out the touch or drag events for that (if that's even possible)

Answer (score 12):

**Try this one:**

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

it worked for me. (supports IE8)

Comment: This works but also causes you to jump to the top when you open a modal when using `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 10):

As of November 2017 Chrome Introduced a new css property

`overscroll-behavior: contain;`

which solves this problem although as of writing has limited cross browser support.

see below links for full details and browser support

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior

Comment: Even in 2020 caniuse puts support of this at only 78%.  Hardly a viable solution.

Comment: In 2022 it seems to get better: https://caniuse.com/?search=overscroll-behavior

Comment: Works good on desktop. Caveats I've noticed (2022 Dec 7). Doesn't work on desktop. Doesn't work for non-scroll-able divs (think divs with `overflow-y:auto` which may or may not be scroll-able at any given point

Answer (score 9):

```
/* =============================
 * Disable / Enable Page Scroll
 * when Bootstrap Modals are
 * shown / hidden
 * ============================= */

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function theMouseWheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', theMouseWheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = theMouseWheel;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', theMouseWheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;  
}

$(function () {
  // disable page scrolling when modal is shown
  $(".modal").on('show', function () { disable_scroll(); });
  // enable page scrolling when modal is hidden
  $(".modal").on('hide', function () { enable_scroll(); });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Couldn't make it work on Chrome just by changing CSS, because I didn't want the page to scroll back to the top. This worked fine:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
  var top = $("body").scrollTop(); $("body").css('position','fixed').css('overflow','hidden').css('top',-top).css('width','100%').css('height',top+5000);
}).on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
  var top = $("body").position().top; $("body").css('position','relative').css('overflow','auto').css('top',0).scrollTop(-top);
});
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me on bootstrap 3.2.

Comment: Had the jump to top issue with angular-material sidenavs. This was the only answer that seems to work in all cases (desktop/mobile + allow scroll in the modal/sidenav + leave the body scroll position fixed without jumping).

Comment: This is also only solution that actually worked for me. tx

Answer (score 9):

Adding the class 'is-modal-open' or modifying style of body tag with javascript is okay and it will work as supposed to. But the problem we gonna face is when the body becomes overflow:hidden, it will jump to the top, ( scrollTop will become 0 ). This will become a usability issue later.

As a solution for this problem, instead of changing body tag overflow:hidden change it on html tag

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('html').css('overflow','auto');
});
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer because the general consensus answer scrolls the page to the top which is a horrible user experience. You should write a blog on this. I ended up turning this into a global solution.

Answer (score 8):

> For **Bootstrap**, you might try this (working on `Firefox`, `Chrome` and `Microsoft Edge`) :

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's 2022, and there are better CSS solutions now.  This works well.  You can add this class to the body element, or modify the body style itself, when the modal is open.

```
  .body-no-scroll {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    touch-action: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
  }
```

Comment: This answer definitely needs more upvotes. Can confirm it works well.

Answer (score 7):

React , if you are looking for

useEffect in the modal that is getting popedup

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    return () =>{
      document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about this code, but it's worth a shot.

In jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(/* Put in your "onModalDisplay" here */)./* whatever */(function() {
        $("#Modal").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
});
```

As I said before, I'm not 100% sure but try anyway.

Comment: This doesn't prevents the body from scrolling while the modal is opened

Comment: @xorinzor you stated in the comments section of charlietfl's answer that this works. But you said: This doesn't prevents the body from scrolling while the modal is opened.

Comment: true but for now its the only solution that partly works and I'm fine with. the reason why I marked his response as answer is because he was earlier with the answer.

Comment: @xorinzor really, i thought i answered before him/her , might be some weird glitch. its fine though

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure this will work with Bootstrap but worth a try - it worked with Remodal.js which can be found on github: http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/ and it would make sense for the methods to be pretty similar.

To stop the page jumping to the top and also prevent the right shift of content add a class to the `body` when the modal is fired and set these CSS rules:

```
body.with-modal {
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

It's the `position:static` and the `height:auto` that combine to stop the jumping of content to the right. The `overflow-y:hidden;` stops the page from being scrollable behind the modal.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is the css-only `body{overflow:hidden}` solution used by most of these answers.  Some answers provide a fix that also prevent the "jump" caused by the disappearing scrollbar; however, none were too elegant.  So, I wrote these two functions, and they seem to work pretty well.

```
var $body = $(window.document.body);

function bodyFreezeScroll() {
    var bodyWidth = $body.innerWidth();
    $body.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $body.css('marginRight', ($body.css('marginRight') ? '+=' : '') + ($body.innerWidth() - bodyWidth))
}

function bodyUnfreezeScroll() {
    var bodyWidth = $body.innerWidth();
    $body.css('marginRight', '-=' + (bodyWidth - $body.innerWidth()))
    $body.css('overflow', 'auto');
}
```

Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngwhk/) to see it in use.

Comment: This is not so old but none of this is working at all for me not even the fiddle I can still scroll the window, what am I missing ?

Comment: Open and Close the modal a few times, and the main green DIV shrinks and shrinks!

Comment: @Webinan I'm not seeing this in Chrome on Win7.  What's your browser and viewport size?

Comment: @smhmic after about 20 times of open and close the green div's width becomes equal to the `open modal` buttons' width. Chrome on 8

Comment: Similar to @jpap's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16451821/5516499) but with added bugs. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Many suggest "overflow: hidden" on the body, which will not work (not in my case at least), since it will make the website scroll to the top.

This is the solution that works for me (both on mobile phones and computers), using jQuery:

```
    $('.yourModalDiv').bind('mouseenter touchstart', function(e) {
        var current = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
            $(window).scrollTop(current);
        });
    });
    $('.yourModalDiv').bind('mouseleave touchend', function(e) {
        $(window).off('scroll');
    });
```

This will make the scrolling of the modal to work, and prevent the website from scrolling at the same time.

Comment: Looks like this solution fixes this iOS bug too: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8

Answer (score 3):

I had to set the viewport-height to get this working perfectly

```
body.modal-open {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following logic, I tested it and it works(even in IE)

```
   <html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var currentScroll=0;
function lockscroll(){
    $(window).scrollTop(currentScroll);
}


$(function(){

        $('#locker').click(function(){
            currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
            $(window).bind('scroll',lockscroll);

        })  


        $('#unlocker').click(function(){
            currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
            $(window).unbind('scroll');

        })
})

</script>

<div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<button id="locker">lock</button>
<button id="unlocker">unlock</button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dh834zgw/1/

the following snippet (using jquery) will disable the window scroll:

```
 var curScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 $('html').toggleClass('noscroll').css('top', '-' + curScrollTop + 'px');
```

And in your css:

```
html.noscroll{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    z-index: 10;
 }
```

Now when you remove the modal, don't forget to remove the noscroll class on the html tag:

```
$('html').toggleClass('noscroll');
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `overflow` be set to `hidden`? +1 though as this worked for me (using `hidden`).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly none of the answers above fixed my issues.

In my situation, the web page originally has a scroll bar. Whenever I click the modal, the scroll bar won't disappear and the header will move to right a bit.

Then I tried to add `.modal-open{overflow:auto;}` (which most people recommended). It indeed fixed the issues: the scroll bar appears after I open the modal. However, another side effect comes out which is that "background below the header will move to the left a bit, together with another long bar behind the modal"

[image: Long bar behind modal]

Luckily, after I add `{padding-right: 0 !important;}`, everything is fixed perfectly. Both the header and body background didn't move and the modal still keeps the scrollbar.

[image: Fixed image]

Hope this can help those who are still stuck with this issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me:

```js
var scrollDistance = 0;
$(document).on("show.bs.modal", ".modal", function () {
    scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("body").css("top", scrollDistance * -1);
});

$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal", function () {
    $("body").css("top", "");
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollDistance);
});
```

```css
.content-area {
  height: 750px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size: 30px;
}

body.modal-open {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="content-area">
   Scroll Down To Modal Button<br/>
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56" height="56" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v11.793l3.146-3.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-4-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L7.5 13.293V1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 1z"/>
   </svg>
</div>

<center class="my-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
</center>


<div class="content-area"></div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically when the modal is opened it will add a negative top for the body to maintain the window scroll position before opening the modal. When closing the modal the window scroll is kept using the same value applied for the top when opening.
This approach prevents body scroll.

**Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sofm3g74/)**

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$("#mymodal").mouseenter(function(){
   $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $("body").css("overflow", "visible");
});
```

Comment: Of all the above answers, this is the first and only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the pieces are here, but I don't see any answer that puts it all together.

The problem is threefold.

(1) prevent the scroll of the underlying page

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
```

(2) and remove the scroll bar

```
var handler = function (e) { e.preventDefault() }
$('.modal').bind('mousewheel touchmove', handler)
```

(3) clean up when the modal is dismissed

```
$('.modal').unbind('mousewheel touchmove', handler)
$('body').css('overflow', '')
```

If the modal is not full-screen then apply the .modal bindings to a full screen overlay.

Comment: This also prevents scrolling within the modal.

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a solution? @Daniel

Comment: @Vay Sort of. Check this out: http://blog.christoffer.me/six-things-i-learnt-about-ios-safaris-rubber-band-scrolling/

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Bootstrap 3:

```
.modal {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
body.modal-open {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

because for me the only `overflow: hidden` on the `body.modal-open` class did not prevent the page from shifting to the left due to the original `margin-right: 15px`.

Answer (score 1):

I just done it this way ...

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

But when the scroller dissapeared it moved everything right 20px, so i added

```
$('body').css('margin-right', '20px');
```

straight after it.

Works for me.

Comment: This only works if the modal is smaller than the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

If modal are 100% height/width "mouseenter/leave" will work to easily enable/disable scrolling. This really worked out for me:

```
var currentScroll=0;
function lockscroll(){
    $(window).scrollTop(currentScroll);
} 
$("#myModal").mouseenter(function(){
    currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).bind('scroll',lockscroll); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
    currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).unbind('scroll',lockscroll); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a sidebar that was generated by checkbox hack.
But the main idea is to save the document scrollTop and not to change it during scrolling the window.

I just didn't like the page jumping when body becomes 'overflow: hidden'.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let prevScrollTop = 0;
    let isSidebarVisible = false;

    document.getElementById('f-overlay-chkbx').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        
        prevScrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        isSidebarVisible = event.target.checked;

        window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
            if (isSidebarVisible) {
                window.scrollTo(0, prevScrollTop);
            }
        });
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since for me this problem presented mainly on iOS, I provide the code to fix that only on iOS:

```
  if(!!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)) {
    var $modalRep    = $('#modal-id'),
        startScrollY = null, 
        moveDiv;  

    $modalRep.on('touchmove', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      moveDiv = startScrollY - ev.touches[0].clientY;
      startScrollY = ev.touches[0].clientY;
      var el = $(ev.target).parents('#div-that-scrolls');
      // #div-that-scrolls is a child of #modal-id
      el.scrollTop(el.scrollTop() + moveDiv);
    });

    $modalRep.on('touchstart', function(ev) {
      startScrollY = ev.touches[0].clientY;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked perfectly for me. So I found another way which works well.

Just add a `scroll.(namespace)` listener and set `scrollTop` of the `document` to the latest of it's value...

and also remove the listener in your close script.

```
// in case of bootstrap modal example:
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  
  var documentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  $(document).on('scroll.noScroll', function() {
     $(document).scrollTop(documentScrollTop);
     return false;
  });

}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {

  $(document).off('scroll.noScroll');

});
```

### update

seems, this does not work well on chrome. any suggestion to fix it ?

Comment: This is a better variation of what I came up with.  But alas, I had the problems with Chrome as well.  It is is still problematic due to strange and unpredictable side effects

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
body.modal-open {
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the best solution:

```
   export const removeBodyScrollingWhenModalOpen = (modalOpen: boolean) => {
        console.log('modalOpen: ', modalOpen);
        const body = document.body;
        if (modalOpen && isMobile()) {
            const scrollY = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--scroll-y');
            body.style.position = 'fixed';
            body.style.top = `-${scrollY}`;
        } else if (!modalOpen && isMobile()) {
            const scrollY = body.style.top;
            body.style.position = '';
            body.style.top = '';
            window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || '0') * -1);
        } else if (modalOpen) {
            document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.body.style.overflowY = 'visible';
        }
    };
```

Comment: I added this to an useEffect in my modal component, I don't know if is the best approach, but it's working.

Comment: @AroldoGoulart I spent like a whole day @ work coming up with different solutions. This seems to work best. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to get the scroll event for the bootstrap 3 modal:

```
$(".modal").scroll(function() {
    console.log("scrolling!);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution for me:

Css:

```
.modal {
     overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

And Js:

```
modalShown = function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
},

modalHidden = function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this vanilla js function to add "modal-open" class to the body. (Based on smhmic's answer)

```
function freezeScroll(show, new_width)
{
    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth,
        clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        new_margin = ((show) ? (new_width + innerWidth - clientWidth) : new_width) + "px";

    document.body.style.marginRight = new_margin;
    document.body.className = (show) ? "modal-open" : "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the overflow and fixing the position does the trick however with my fluid design it would fix it past the browsers width, so a width:100% fixed that.

```
body.modal-open{overflow:hidden;position:fixed;width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.entry_details').dialog({
    width:800,
    height:500,
    draggable: true,
    title: entry.short_description,
    closeText: "Zamknij",
    open: function(){
        //    blokowanie scrolla dla body
        var body_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            $(document).scrollTop(body_scroll);
        });
    },
    close: function(){
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `overflow: hidden` in HTML for a better cross-platform performance.

I would use

```
html.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
   });
   $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
   });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A small note for those in SharePoint 2013. The body already has `overflow: hidden`. What you are looking for is to set `overflow: hidden` on div element with id `s4-workspace`, e.g.

```
var body = document.getElementById('s4-workspace');
body.className = body.className+" modal-open";
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me

```
$('#myModal').on({'mousewheel': function(e) 
    {
    if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above occurs when you use a modal inside another modal. When I open a modal inside another modal, the closing of the latter removes the class `modal-open` from the `body`. The fix of the issue depends on how you close the latter modal.

If you close the modal with html like,

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Then you have to add a listener like this,

```
$(modalSelector).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    return false;
});
```

If you close the modal using javascript like,

```
$(modalSelector).modal("hide");
```

Then you have to run the command some time after like this,

```
setInterval(function(){$("body").addClass("modal-open");}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do that as Bulma does?
When modal is-active then add to html their class .is-clipped which is overflow: hidden!important;
And thats it.

Edit: Okey, Bulma has this bug, so you must add also other things like

```
html.is-modal-active {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my vanilla JS solution based on @jpap jquery:

```
let bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// lock body scroll
    let width = bodyElement.scrollWidth;
    bodyElement.classList.add('overflow-hidden');
    bodyElement.style.width = width + 'px';

// unlock body scroll
    bodyElement.classList.remove('overflow-hidden');
    bodyElement.style.width = 'auto';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in React to fix this issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isShown) {
    const width = document.body.clientWidth;
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.body.style.width = `${width}px`;
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
    document.body.style.width = `auto`;
  }

  return () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
    document.body.style.width = `auto`;
  };
}, [isShown]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I read most answers with a focus on React.

**Best solution for my React functional component** was to use solution provided originally by @arcticmatt

I included some improvements that were mentioned in other answers in the code example bellow (pay attention to the useEffect definition):

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from "react";

export default function PopoverMenu({className, handleClose, children}) {
  const selfRef = useRef(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isPopoverOpenned = selfRef.current?.style.display !== "none";
    const focusedElement = document?.activeElement;
    const scrollPosition = {x: window.scrollX, y: window.scrollY};
    if (isPopoverOpenned) {
      preventDocBodyScrolling();
    } else {
      restoreDocBodyScrolling();
    }

    function preventDocBodyScrolling() {
      const width = document.body.clientWidth;
      const hasVerticalScrollBar = (window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth);
      document.body.style.overflowX = "hidden";
      document.body.style.overflowY = hasVerticalScrollBar ? "scroll" : "";
      document.body.style.width = `${width}px`;
      document.body.style.position = "fixed";

    }

    function restoreDocBodyScrolling() {
      document.body.style.overflowX = "";
      document.body.style.overflowY = "";
      document.body.style.width = "";
      document.body.style.position = "";
      focusedElement?.focus();
      window.scrollTo(scrollPosition.x, scrollPosition.y);
    }


    return () => {
      restoreDocBodyScrolling(); // cleanup on unmount
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="backdrop"
        onClick={() => handleClose && handleClose()}
      />
      <div
        className={`pop-over-menu${className ? (` ${className}`) : ""}`}
        ref={selfRef}
      >
        <button
          className="pop-over-menu--close-button" type="button"
          onClick={() => handleClose && handleClose()}
        >
          X
        </button>
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most famous answer is simple i.e.

```
body{
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

but what will be the solution if you want to open a modal in a child/grand-child and stop the scroll? Well the longer solution will be to use props or store in Angular/React and change the height and overflow property of body tag.

Another solution can just be by getting the body from the child/grand-child component and change its height and overflow accordingly to stop scrolling.
In my case I just did this

```
if(isModalExpanded){
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.body.style.height = "100%";
}
else{
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    document.body.style.height = "auto";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Hack**

use **CSS** `:has()`

**If this class is available in the DOM, overflow will get hidden for Body**

```
body:has(.show_popup) {
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

MDN : **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has**

Answer (score -1):

This issue is fixed,
Solution: Just open your bootstap.css and change as below

```
body.modal-open,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

to

```
 body.modal-open,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
}
```

Please view the below youtube video only less than 3min your issue will fix...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX7wPNMob_E

Comment: Any one try with this...?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the whole question. It's not about positioning the scrollbar, it's about preventing to be able to scroll in the background with your mousewheel on pc or finger on mobile devices.

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution in TypeScript that allows easy extension of events to be prevented and deals with mobile devices as well. This also will **not** cause a horizontal jump when disabling the vertical scrollbar.
Just use the exported functions at the bottom on e.g. a `onclick` handler on any HTML element. If not running in a NodeJS environment, simply delete the `process.client` checks.

```
/**
 * Handles scroll events for modal content
 */

const events = [
  'DOMMouseScroll',
  'mousewheel',
  'wheel',
  'touchmove',
  'keydown',
  'mousedown',
  'scroll',
];

const preventDefault = (e: Event) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};

let currentY: number;

const disableScroll = () => {
  currentY = window.scrollY;

  events.forEach((event) => {
    window.addEventListener(event, preventDefault, {
      passive: false,
    });
  });

  const bodyStyle = document.body.style;
  bodyStyle.setProperty('touch-action', 'none');
  bodyStyle.setProperty('position', 'fixed');
  bodyStyle.setProperty('overflow-y', 'scroll');
  bodyStyle.setProperty('width', '100%');
  bodyStyle.setProperty('top', `-${currentY}px`);
};

const enableScroll = () => {
  events.forEach((event) => {
    window.removeEventListener(event, preventDefault);
  });

  const bodyStyle = document.body.style;
  bodyStyle.removeProperty('touch-action');
  bodyStyle.removeProperty('position');
  bodyStyle.removeProperty('overflow-y');
  bodyStyle.removeProperty('width');
  bodyStyle.removeProperty('top');
  window.scroll(0, currentY);
};

/**
 * Makes a component (e.g. popup) modal
 */
export const makeModal = () => {
  if (process.client) {
    disableScroll();
  }
};

/**
 * Makes a component (e.g. popup) non-modal
 */
export const makeNonModal = () => {
  if (process.client) {
    enableScroll();
  }
};
```

Answer (score -3):

I found a working solution after doing some 8-10 hours research on StackOverflow itself.

The breakthrough

```
$('.modal').is(':visible');
```

So I have built a function to check if any modal is open which will periodically add class *modal-open** to the

```
 setInterval(function()
     {
         if($('.modal').is(':visible')===true)
         {
             $("body").addClass("modal-open");
         }
         else
         {
             $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
         }

     },200);
```

> The reason to use **$(".modal")** here is because all modals (in Bootstrap) use class **modal** (fade/show is as per the state)

So my modals are now running perfectly without the body getting scrolled.

This is a bug/unheard issue in GitHub as well but nobody's bothered.

Comment: I'm sure this works, and it's probably even performant if it's the only thing on the page, but as your app grows adding more intervals like this will add up to the slow death of your app's performance.

Comment: Rather than polling every 200ms, it would be better to assign an event handler on modal open. E.g. something like `$("body").on("show.bs.modal", ".modal", function() { $("body").addClass("modal-open"); });`

Answer (score -6):

HTML:

```
<body onscroll="stop_scroll()">
```

javascript:

```
function stop_scroll(){
    scroll(0,0) ;
}
```

If you set a flag `(bool)` inside `stop_scroll()`, you can decide when to engage it (if you want it only temporarely).

This will reset scrolling every time some element overflows the `body` boundaries and the windows tends to scroll (this is totally independent of scrollbars; `overflow : hidden` has nothing to do with it).