# How do I avoid background page scrolling?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's modal window, and I noticed when you scroll, the modal popup stays fixed while the background page moves. For demo, you can click on "Launch demo modal" button in the following page:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

How do I avoid that and let scroll event controls the modal window instead? The options Bootstrap offers does not seem to include that.

The modal pop up is a `<div>` with `position: fixed`, and that is why it stays fixed when I scroll. However I can't set it to other values since it needs to stay popped up. Also i figured that if I set `<body>`'s style to `overflow:hidden`, the scroll bar will be hidden. But that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.modal') 
.on('shown', function(){ 
console.log('show'); 
$('body').css({overflow: 'hidden'}); 
}) 
.on('hidden', function(){ 
$('body').css({overflow: ''}); 
});
```

Comment: i think this will not come handy if the height of the modal is more. if you are hiding the overflow then it is a must that height of the modal should be less then height of window, and this is not a good practice. You cant be sure of this. this is like hardcoding

Answer (score 1):

You can add `overflow: hidden` on `body.modal-open` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013994/633406)

Comment: This is slightly different from what I want - the scroll bar should still show up and work and I want it control the modal pop up instead of the background page.

Comment: If there's too much text on the modal, the modal will have a scroll bar and you'll be able to scroll it. You're saying you want the contents of the modal to scroll when you scroll the background area?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the shift with

```
body{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
}
```