# Disable scrolling on body in overlay modal view

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, modernizr

I am using [this script](http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/index.html) to display and hide a modal view, but I want to disable scrolling on body once the modal view is opened and disable it when it is closed.

I tried to modify the JS code but it works but it breaks the opening animation. here is the code modified:

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
    bodyTag = document.querySelector( 'body' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

function toggleOverlay() {

    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );

        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }

            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            classie.remove( bodyTag, 'noscroll' );
        };
        if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( bodyTag, 'noscroll' );
    }
}

triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );})();
```

Original Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xv6A/421/)

Answer (score 7):

First add jquery. Download from https://jquery.com and add it to your document with `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Then, at the bottom of the document (your document with your animation) add the following snip:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#trigger-overlay').click(function() {
            $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            });
        });
        $('.overlay-close').click(function() {
            $('html').css('overflow', 'scroll');
            $('body').unbind('touchmove');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried this with code from https://github.com/codrops/FullscreenOverlayStyles and animation `Huge inc`. This will prevent scrolling of text when animation is open.

**Updated my answer**, first answer did allow scrolling on touch devices.

Answer (score 1):

already discussed here: [Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened)

it is using bootstrap, but the same solution can still work. the second answer is a bit better than the accepted one. it suggests toggling a class on the body that makes the body `overflow: hidden;` when the modal is open.

Comment: If you look at my code you will find that I tried to implement this solution, but as I mention it does not work, it breaks the animation