# How to make modal scrollable when set the background fixed?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

At first, I got the same problem like:

[How to prevent background scroll when bootstrap modal is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524718/how-to-prevent-background-scroll-when-bootstrap-modal-is-open)

[Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened)

[bootstrap-issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15852)

```
Bootstrap3.3.5
jQuery2.1.4
Bootstrap-material-design
```

My first problem is when I use Safari 601.1 on iPhone and iPad(both run on iOS9) tring to open the modal and scroll it, the modal didn't scroll but the background scroll.I follow the advise above.like add

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

in css or add some js script. the modal fixed as they said.But another problem appear, I can't scroll the modal anymore, even when the modal content is longer than the screen. like this

[image]

I also tried set the modal

```
body.modal-open {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and wanna it become fix the screen, but it doesn't work.

#### Edit

What is wired is when I closed the modal and open again, everything works well! I guess it is something about the image in the modal had been loaded at the first time.
Any idea?

#### Edit2

I followed @Vignesh Pandi's advice, first time I open the modal the modal style is

```
z-index: 1040; display: block;
```

and the second time is

```
z-index: 1040; display: block; padding-left: 0px;
```

I add the z-index because I have multi modal in single page, I add this:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
    $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
}, 0);
```

});

to make the modal index correct.After add padding-left: 0px when modal show up didn't solve this problem.And I also try add

```
overflow: hidden; position: fixed;
```

in my css, as I sadi, it work well when the page is not longer than the screen, but I can't scrool the modal when the I got a very long page.In face, I got an online example, Hope this would help [modal-issue](https://unicooo.com/act/Windson/KISS-STRANGER/)

Comment: You need to set the height of modal body to some value and make overflow overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: Or if you are allowed to use js than there is a js called mcustomscroll http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: It works well when I close the modal and open it again.

Comment: Is your bug got resolved ?

Comment: @Vignesh Pandi, no, I had edit my question, and don't know why that happen.

Comment: Can you check which style is not been applied during the first time opening of modal  ? which is being applied after the first time ?

Comment: And trying applying your style dynamically after the modal being loaded like this :
$('#yourModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('body').removeClass('stopsscroll');
})

$('#yourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('body').addClass('stopsscroll');
})

<style>
.stopsscroll{
 overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
</style>

Comment: Thanks @Vignesh Pandi, I tried your code but still have this problem.I have edit my question and have an online example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according [bootstrap-issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14839)

I set

```
.modal {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

fix the problem!