# Prevent BODY from scrolling when modal is opened AND input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Similar question to this one here:

[Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened)

```
.modal{
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body.modal--open{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

The above CSS works fine, but the problem is when the user focuses on an input field within the modal the body scrolls again. Is there something that can be done to prevent this?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe move modal--open to root? `html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}`

Comment: actually that did work! if you apply to both html and body!

Comment: Excellent! If you don't mind, please upvote my comment containing the answer.

Comment: Remove overflow:hidden and try adding position:fixed