# Prevent BODY from scrolling when a modal is opened and CSS3 is included

Tags: html, css

I know this is a frequently asked question, but the solution to add `body.modal-open {overflow:hidden;}` to solve this problem as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9538868/4314952) won't work, if CSS3 is included.

- See for example this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dHc2xTRPTw), where it is possible to scroll the body.
- Same example without including CSS3 -> [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hHF6C16VPV). The standard solution works perfectly.

How can I prevent the Body from scrolling when modal is opened and CSS3 is included?

Comment: can this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9280412/1098851 help? (see demos)

Comment: Yes, adding the `noscroll` class to the body when the modal is opened fix the problem. http://www.bootply.com/Q1cqaJTGdF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the class `noscroll` to the body when the modal is open, solves the problem.

JS:

```
$("#myModal").on("show", function () {
  $("body").addClass("noscroll");
}).on("hidden", function () {
  $("body").removeClass("noscroll")
});
```

CSS:

```
.noscroll { overflow: hidden; }
```

See on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/9FQgyqIkvl).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

in the open callback of the modal, and revert it onClose

Comment: Did you tried it? Because the css rule from my example makes exactly this and it isn't working.

Comment: This will work. In your example, you have ``html { overflow-x: hidden }`` which doesn't apply vertically

Comment: But both bootply examples have `overflow:hidden` ?!

Comment: Check this
http://luxiyalu.com/playground/overlay/ from this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling/9280412#9280412