# How to prevent background scrolling when Materializecss modal open on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

How to prevent background scrolling when materializecss modal open on mobile platforms? On desktop browsers the background is prevented from scrolling and works as it should.

On mobile browsers (Safari ios, Chrome ios, etc), when a modal is opened and using your finger to scroll it, the background also scrolls as does the modal. How do I prevent that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened

Comment: It works for background scroll but in the popup I want it to be scrollable. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I propose you should do something like: .modal{ overflow:scroll}

Comment: Just checked my materializecss page on mobile (andoird L, chrome) modal window scrolls but background does not. Do you have any codes to share?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Wrap your page into a `div`, and when the modal is open you add `overflow: hidden` in the `div`. And be sure if the modal doesn't inherit the `overflow` from the page wrapper.

I hope it helps.