# Prevent background page from scrolling in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4 on my website. The webpage contains articles consisting of text and an image.

[image: Page View]

When you click on the image an enlarge image pop up in a modal like this.

[image]

But the problem is on modal opening the page scrolls to the top of the page.
Is there any method I can prevent automatic scrolling of my page on modal opening.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by applying CSS when you fire event of open your image 
i.e.
Just Apply `Overflow:hidden` to your `body` as shown bellow

Try this

**Script**

```
$("#YourModalID").on("show", function () {
  $("body").addClass("modal-open");
}).on("hidden", function () {
  $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
});
```

**CSS**

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Refer same quetion on [Prevent BODY from scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened) which explains above better

Answer (score 1):

kindly check positions of your bootsrap4 modal in css.. Bootsrap4 explained clearly in [bootsrap4 modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/)

Additionally, you can refer this simple example to understand the behavior of [images modal popup](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp)