# Prevent body from scrolling when an overlay is opened, without jump to top, without left/right jumping?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar, overlay

What's the best way to prevent body from scrolling when an overlay is opened (modal, side-nav...)?

I'm looking for something that would solve the following problems:

- Page jump to top (overflow:hidden on body)
- Page jump from right to left when scrollbar disappears (overflow:hidden on body)
- Keep scrolling inside the overlay
- Works on both mobile and desktop

I have already tried the solutions proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24727206/8132424
But none of them seemed perfect.

Do you have any idea? Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you already seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling ?

Comment: Where is your overlay code? 
Please paste your CSS for overlay to understand. or create a fiddle.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('button').on('click', function(){
                $('.modal').addClass('active');
                $('body').addClass('modal-open');
            });
            $('.close').on('click', function(){
                $('.modal').removeClass('active');
                $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            });
        });
```

```css
        .body-container{
            max-width: 1200px;
            width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color: #dddddd;
            padding:10px;
        }
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;
}
.modal.active {
    display: flex;
}
.inner {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="body-container">
        <button>Click</button>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ipsa, beatae molestias. Optio et atque consequatur. Aut ipsam, fuga nesciunt perspiciatis accusamus consequatur culpa omnis. Error fuga accusantium voluptatem magni.
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
       <div class="inner">
        <span class="close">X</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque optio numquam consequatur, nostrum saepe rerum explicabo dignissimos quos maxime amet, qui repudiandae perferendis vel, id quaerat, quidem quo ad! Ipsum!
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try this code to stop jumping elements.

```js
// opens modal without jumping
    $('.modal_open').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.modal_popup').addClass('open');
      $('body').css({
        "overflow-y": "hidden",
        "padding-right": getScrollbarWidth() + 'px'
      });
      // getScrollbarWidth();
    });
    // close popup by outside click
    $('.modal_popup').click(function() {
      $('.modal_popup').removeClass('open');
      $('body').css({
        "overflow-y": "auto",
        "padding-right": '0px'
       });
    });
    $('.modal_popup > div').click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
     });
    function getScrollbarWidth() {
      var outer = document.createElement("div");
      outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
      outer.style.width = "100px";
      document.body.appendChild(outer);

      var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
      // force scrollbars
      outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

      // add innerdiv
      var inner = document.createElement("div");
      inner.style.width = "100%";
      outer.appendChild(inner);        

      var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;

      // remove divs
      outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

      return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
  }
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.body_scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal_popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.modal_popup.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.modal_popup > div {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body_scroll">
    <a href="#" class="modal_open">Click to open modal</a>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal_popup">
    <div>Click outside to close the popup</div>
  </div>
```