# Stop scrolling while viewing a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I've made a modal by loosely following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp). The problem is that I don't want to be able to scroll the rest of the page while the modal is showing. How can this be done?

Comment: This has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened

Comment: @Bromox that's a bootstrap modal so that is different and could be misleading. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?