# Enable and disable scrolling without changing the window size

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on the button, I show a pop-up on the right and I do `body {overflow: hide;}` to prevent page scrolling. When closing the pop-up, I do `body {overflow: auto}`. I have a window size changing and it's not good.

Tell me how to properly enable and disable the scroll without changing the window size?

Comment: Question is rather vague... Perhaps your popup should be 'position: absolute' so it does not affect the content flow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451821/1427878

Answer (score 0):

**Disable scroll:**

```
document.body.style.paddingRight = `${window.innerWidth - document.body.offsetWidth}px`
document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden'
```

**Enable scroll:**

```
document.body.style.paddingRight = '0px'
document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).