# make page stop scrolling when lightbox is active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following lightbox which includes a form. Everything works fine. My only problem is how to make the html page stop scrolling when the lightbox is active.

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick="
  document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<img src="img/add.jpg"/></a></p>
<div id="light" class="white_content">

<input name="degree_1" type="text" size="73"
   value="<?php echo $user_data_profile_education['degree_1'];?>"/>
</br></br>
Grade</br>
<input name="grade_1" type="text" size="73"
   value="<?php echo $user_data_profile_education['grade_1'];?>"/>

<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick="
  document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"> 
</br><img src="img/done_editing.jpg"/> </a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

and this is my **css**:

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220%;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}


.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 32%;
    height: 51%;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-left:50px;
    border: 5px solid green;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling

Comment: If you want the lightbox content to be stationary even with the scroll of pages, you can set the lightbox css to position: fixed;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add overflow: hidden to your body when you show the lightbox and overflow: auto when you hide it.

Comment: Add document.body.style.overflow='hidden' to the onclick event of the link that shows the lightbox and document.body.style.overflow='auto' to the onclick event of the link that hides it.

Comment: Great answer, simple and effective, +1'd.

Comment: This causes the scrollbar to disappear while it's hidden, which widens the page slightly, reflowing text, so there's an ugly visual jump.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS. Setting `overflow: hidden` on the body does not stop it from scrolling.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use onLoad/onClose to change the css of the div that holds the page content

Setting .lb_overlay height is a nice touch, add the same "margin" from the top of the modal to the bottom so scrolling to the bottom doesn't just sit right at the bottom of the window

```
var modal = $("#modal"),
    wrapper = $("#wrapper")

$("#modalTrigger").click(function(){
    modal.lightbox_me({
        centered: true,
        onLoad : function(){
            wrapper.css({
                "position" : "fixed",
                "width" : "100%"
            })
            $(".lb_overlay").css("height" , parseInt($(window).height()) + parseInt(modal.css("top") ) + "px" )
        },
        onClose : function(){
            wrapper.css("position" , "relative")
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still needs it, you can use lightbox events:

```
let lg = document.getElementById('lightgallery');

lg.addEventListener('onAfterOpen', function(e) {
    $("html, body").css("overflow","hidden");
}, false);

lightGallery(lg);

lg.addEventListener('onCloseAfter', function(e) {
    $("html, body").css("overflow","auto");
}, false);

lightGallery(lg);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add this script to disable scrollign in lighbox

```
<script>
        lightbox.option({
    disableScrolling:true
    })
</script>
```