# How to stop background scroll body when a modal/lightbox is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox2

I am using the lightbox jquery plugin to open a lightbox when a user clicks on a product. Often the lightbox content stretches below the fold, and at the moment the right scrollbar moves the entire page when you scroll down.

I'd like it to work like the pinterest lightbox, whereby the right scrollbar only scrolls the lightbox, and the rest of the page stays fixed. I've seen a few posts on this, but nothing seems to work for me.

Problem is I want the lightbox to scroll if the content is bigger than the viewport of the browser but not the background.

I grabbed this lightbox script from here:

> //
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- // //  Lightbox v2.04 //  by Lokesh Dhakar -
> http://www.lokeshdhakar.com //  Last Modification: 2/9/08 // //  For
> more information, visit: //
> http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ // //  Licensed under the
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- /*

CSS:

```
#lightbox{  position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 100; text-align: center; line-height: 0;}
#lightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#lightbox a img{ border: none; }

#outerImageContainer{ position: relative; background-color: #fff; width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
#imageContainer{ padding: 10px; }

#loading{ position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 0%; height: 25%; width: 100%; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
#hoverNav{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 10; }
#imageContainer>#hoverNav{ left: 0;}
#hoverNav a{ outline: none;}

#prevLink, #nextLink{ width: 49%; height: 100%; background-image: url(data:image2/gif;base64,AAAA); /* Trick IE into showing hover */ display: block; }
#prevLink { left: 0; float: left;}
#nextLink { right: 0; float: right;}
#prevLink:hover, #prevLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images2/prevlabel.gif) left 15% no-repeat; }
#nextLink:hover, #nextLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images2/nextlabel.gif) right 15% no-repeat; }

#imageDataContainer{ font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.4em; overflow: auto; width: 100% ; }

#imageData{ padding:0 10px; color: #666; }
#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; }  
#imageData #caption{ font-weight: bold; }
#imageData #numberDisplay{ display: block; clear: left; padding-bottom: 1.0em;  }           
#imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: right;  padding-bottom: 0.7em; outline: none;}      

#overlay{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 90; width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: #000; }
```

JSS:

```
    Table of Contents
    -----------------
    Configuration

    Lightbox Class Declaration
    - initialize()
    - updateImageList()
    - start()
    - changeImage()
    - resizeImageContainer()
    - showImage()
    - updateDetails()
    - updateNav()
    - enableKeyboardNav()
    - disableKeyboardNav()
    - keyboardAction()
    - preloadNeighborImages()
    - end()

    Function Calls
    - document.observe()

*/ // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// //  Configurationl // LightboxOptions = Object.extend({
    fileLoadingImage:        'images2/loading.gif',     
    fileBottomNavCloseImage: 'images2/closelabel.gif',

    overlayOpacity: 0.8,   // controls transparency of shadow overlay

    animate: true,         // toggles resizing animations
    resizeSpeed: 7,        // controls the speed of the image resizing animations (1=slowest and 10=fastest)

    borderSize: 10,         //if you adjust the padding in the CSS, you will need to update this variable

    // When grouping images this is used to write: Image # of #.
    // Change it for non-english localization
    labelImage: "Image",
    labelOf: "of" }, window.LightboxOptions || {});

//
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var Lightbox = Class.create();

Lightbox.prototype = {
    imageArray: [],
    activeImage: undefined,

    // initialize()
    // Constructor runs on completion of the DOM loading. Calls updateImageList and then
    // the function inserts html at the bottom of the page which is used to display the shadow 
    // overlay and the image container.
    //
    initialize: function() {    

        this.updateImageList();

        this.keyboardAction = this.keyboardAction.bindAsEventListener(this);

        if (LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed > 10) LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed = 10;
        if (LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed < 1)  LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed = 1;

        this.resizeDuration = LightboxOptions.animate ? ((11 - LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed) * 0.15) : 0;
        this.overlayDuration = LightboxOptions.animate ? 0.2 : 0;  // shadow fade in/out duration

        // When Lightbox starts it will resize itself from 250 by 250 to the current image dimension.
        // If animations are turned off, it will be hidden as to prevent a flicker of a
        // white 250 by 250 box.
        var size = (LightboxOptions.animate ? 250 : 1) + 'px';


        // Code inserts html at the bottom of the page that looks similar to this:
        //
        //  <div id="overlay"></div>
        //  <div id="lightbox">
        //      <div id="outerImageContainer">
        //          <div id="imageContainer">
        //              <img id="lightboxImage">
        //              <div style="" id="hoverNav">
        //                  <a href="#" id="prevLink"></a>
        //                  <a href="#" id="nextLink"></a>
        //              </div>
        //              <div id="loading">
        //                  <a href="#" id="loadingLink">
        //                      <img src="images/loading.gif">
        //                  </a>
        //              </div>
        //          </div>
        //      </div>
        //      <div id="imageDataContainer">
        //          <div id="imageData">
        //              <div id="imageDetails">
        //                  <span id="caption"></span>
        //                  <span id="numberDisplay"></span>
        //              </div>
        //              <div id="bottomNav">
        //                  <a href="#" id="bottomNavClose">
        //                      <img src="images/close.gif">
        //                  </a>
        //              </div>
        //          </div>
        //      </div>
        //  </div>


        var objBody = $$('body')[0];

        objBody.appendChild(Builder.node('div',{id:'overlay'}));

        objBody.appendChild(Builder.node('div',{id:'lightbox'}, [
            Builder.node('div',{id:'outerImageContainer'}, 
                Builder.node('div',{id:'imageContainer'}, [
                    Builder.node('img',{id:'lightboxImage'}), 
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'hoverNav'}, [
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'prevLink', href: '#' }),
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'nextLink', href: '#' })
                    ]),
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'loading'}, 
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'loadingLink', href: '#' }, 
                            Builder.node('img', {src: LightboxOptions.fileLoadingImage})
                        )
                    )
                ])
            ),
            Builder.node('div', {id:'imageDataContainer'},
                Builder.node('div',{id:'imageData'}, [
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'imageDetails'}, [
                        Builder.node('span',{id:'caption'}),
                        Builder.node('span',{id:'numberDisplay'})
                    ]),
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'bottomNav'},
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'bottomNavClose', href: '#' },
                            Builder.node('img', { src: LightboxOptions.fileBottomNavCloseImage })
                        )
                    )
                ])
            )
        ]));


        $('overlay').hide().observe('click', (function() { this.end(); }).bind(this));
        $('lightbox').hide().observe('click', (function(event) { if (event.element().id == 'lightbox') this.end(); }).bind(this));
        $('outerImageContainer').setStyle({ width: size, height: size });
        $('prevLink').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.changeImage(this.activeImage - 1); }).bindAsEventListener(this));
        $('nextLink').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.changeImage(this.activeImage + 1); }).bindAsEventListener(this));
        $('loadingLink').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.end(); }).bind(this));
        $('bottomNavClose').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.end(); }).bind(this));

        var th = this;
        (function(){
            var ids = 
                'overlay lightbox outerImageContainer imageContainer lightboxImage hoverNav prevLink nextLink loading loadingLink ' + 
                'imageDataContainer imageData imageDetails caption numberDisplay bottomNav bottomNavClose';   
            $w(ids).each(function(id){ th[id] = $(id); });
        }).defer();
    },

    //
    // updateImageList()
    // Loops through anchor tags looking for 'lightbox' references and applies onclick
    // events to appropriate links. You can rerun after dynamically adding images w/ajax.
    //
    updateImageList: function() {   
        this.updateImageList = Prototype.emptyFunction;

        document.observe('click', (function(event){
            var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]') || event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
            if (target) {
                event.stop();
                this.start(target);
            }
        }).bind(this));
    },

    //
    //  start()
    //  Display overlay and lightbox. If image is part of a set, add siblings to imageArray.
    //
    start: function(imageLink) {    

        $$('select', 'object', 'embed').each(function(node){ node.style.visibility = 'hidden' });

        // stretch overlay to fill page and fade in
        var arrayPageSize = this.getPageSize();
        $('overlay').setStyle({ width: arrayPageSize[0] + 'px', height: arrayPageSize[1] + 'px' });

        new Effect.Appear(this.overlay, { duration: this.overlayDuration, from: 0.0, to: LightboxOptions.overlayOpacity });

        this.imageArray = [];
        var imageNum = 0;       

        if ((imageLink.rel == 'lightbox')){
            // if image is NOT part of a set, add single image to imageArray
            this.imageArray.push([imageLink.href, imageLink.title]);         
        } else {
            // if image is part of a set..
            this.imageArray = 
                $$(imageLink.tagName + '[href][rel="' + imageLink.rel + '"]').
                collect(function(anchor){ return [anchor.href, anchor.title]; }).
                uniq();

            while (this.imageArray[imageNum][0] != imageLink.href) { imageNum++; }
        }

        // calculate top and left offset for the lightbox 
        var arrayPageScroll = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets();
        var lightboxTop = arrayPageScroll[1] + (document.viewport.getHeight() / 10);
        var lightboxLeft = arrayPageScroll[0];
        this.lightbox.setStyle({ top: lightboxTop + 'px', left: lightboxLeft + 'px' }).show();

        this.changeImage(imageNum);
    },

    //
    //  changeImage()
    //  Hide most elements and preload image in preparation for resizing image container.
    //
    changeImage: function(imageNum) {   

        this.activeImage = imageNum; // update global var

        // hide elements during transition
        if (LightboxOptions.animate) this.loading.show();
        this.lightboxImage.hide();
        this.hoverNav.hide();
        this.prevLink.hide();
        this.nextLink.hide();
        // HACK: Opera9 does not currently support scriptaculous opacity and appear fx
        this.imageDataContainer.setStyle({opacity: .0001});
        this.numberDisplay.hide();      

        var imgPreloader = new Image();

        // once image is preloaded, resize image container


        imgPreloader.onload = (function(){
            this.lightboxImage.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage][0];
            this.resizeImageContainer(imgPreloader.width, imgPreloader.height);
        }).bind(this);
        imgPreloader.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage][0];
    },

    //
    //  resizeImageContainer()
    //
    resizeImageContainer: function(imgWidth, imgHeight) {

        // get current width and height
        var widthCurrent  = this.outerImageContainer.getWidth();
        var heightCurrent = this.outerImageContainer.getHeight();

        // get new width and height
        var widthNew  = (imgWidth  + LightboxOptions.borderSize * 2);
        var heightNew = (imgHeight + LightboxOptions.borderSize * 2);

        // scalars based on change from old to new
        var xScale = (widthNew  / widthCurrent)  * 100;
        var yScale = (heightNew / heightCurrent) * 100;

        // calculate size difference between new and old image, and resize if necessary
        var wDiff = widthCurrent - widthNew;
        var hDiff = heightCurrent - heightNew;

        if (hDiff != 0) new Effect.Scale(this.outerImageContainer, yScale, {scaleX: false, duration: this.resizeDuration, queue: 'front'}); 
        if (wDiff != 0) new Effect.Scale(this.outerImageContainer, xScale, {scaleY: false, duration: this.resizeDuration, delay: this.resizeDuration}); 

        // if new and old image are same size and no scaling transition is necessary, 
        // do a quick pause to prevent image flicker.
        var timeout = 0;
        if ((hDiff == 0) && (wDiff == 0)){
            timeout = 100;
            if (Prototype.Browser.IE) timeout = 250;   
        }

        (function(){
            this.prevLink.setStyle({ height: imgHeight + 'px' });
            this.nextLink.setStyle({ height: imgHeight + 'px' });
            this.imageDataContainer.setStyle({ width: widthNew + 'px' });

            this.showImage();
        }).bind(this).delay(timeout / 1000);
    },

    //
    //  showImage()
    //  Display image and begin preloading neighbors.
    //
    showImage: function(){
        this.loading.hide();
        new Effect.Appear(this.lightboxImage, { 
            duration: this.resizeDuration, 
            queue: 'end', 
            afterFinish: (function(){ this.updateDetails(); }).bind(this) 
        });
        this.preloadNeighborImages();
    },

    //
    //  updateDetails()
    //  Display caption, image number, and bottom nav.
    //
    updateDetails: function() {

        // if caption is not null
        if (this.imageArray[this.activeImage][1] != ""){
            this.caption.update(this.imageArray[this.activeImage][1]).show();
        }

        // if image is part of set display 'Image x of x' 
        if (this.imageArray.length > 1){
            this.numberDisplay.update( LightboxOptions.labelImage + ' ' + (this.activeImage + 1) + ' ' + LightboxOptions.labelOf + '  ' + this.imageArray.length).show();
        }

        new Effect.Parallel(
            [ 
                new Effect.SlideDown(this.imageDataContainer, { sync: true, duration: this.resizeDuration, from: 0.0, to: 1.0 }), 
                new Effect.Appear(this.imageDataContainer, { sync: true, duration: this.resizeDuration }) 
            ], 
            { 
                duration: this.resizeDuration, 
                afterFinish: (function() {
                    // update overlay size and update nav
                    var arrayPageSize = this.getPageSize();
                    this.overlay.setStyle({ height: arrayPageSize[1] + 'px' });
                    this.updateNav();
                }).bind(this)
            } 
        );
    },

    //
    //  updateNav()
    //  Display appropriate previous and next hover navigation.
    //
    updateNav: function() {

        this.hoverNav.show();               

        // if not first image in set, display prev image button
        if (this.activeImage > 0) this.prevLink.show();

        // if not last image in set, display next image button
        if (this.activeImage < (this.imageArray.length - 1)) this.nextLink.show();

        this.enableKeyboardNav();
    },

    //
    //  enableKeyboardNav()
    //
    enableKeyboardNav: function() {
        document.observe('keydown', this.keyboardAction); 
    },

    //
    //  disableKeyboardNav()
    //
    disableKeyboardNav: function() {
        document.stopObserving('keydown', this.keyboardAction); 
    },

    //
    //  keyboardAction()
    //
    keyboardAction: function(event) {
        var keycode = event.keyCode;

        var escapeKey;
        if (event.DOM_VK_ESCAPE) {  // mozilla
            escapeKey = event.DOM_VK_ESCAPE;
        } else { // ie
            escapeKey = 27;
        }

        var key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();

        if (key.match(/x|o|c/) || (keycode == escapeKey)){ // close lightbox
            this.end();
        } else if ((key == 'p') || (keycode == 37)){ // display previous image
            if (this.activeImage != 0){
                this.disableKeyboardNav();
                this.changeImage(this.activeImage - 1);
            }
        } else if ((key == 'n') || (keycode == 39)){ // display next image
            if (this.activeImage != (this.imageArray.length - 1)){
                this.disableKeyboardNav();
                this.changeImage(this.activeImage + 1);
            }
        }
    },

    //
    //  preloadNeighborImages()
    //  Preload previous and next images.
    //
    preloadNeighborImages: function(){
        var preloadNextImage, preloadPrevImage;
        if (this.imageArray.length > this.activeImage + 1){
            preloadNextImage = new Image();
            preloadNextImage.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage + 1][0];
        }
        if (this.activeImage > 0){
            preloadPrevImage = new Image();
            preloadPrevImage.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage - 1][0];
        }

    },

    //
    //  end()
    //
    end: function() {
        this.disableKeyboardNav();
        this.lightbox.hide();
        new Effect.Fade(this.overlay, { duration: this.overlayDuration });
        $$('select', 'object', 'embed').each(function(node){ node.style.visibility = 'visible' });
    },

    //
    //  getPageSize()
    //
    getPageSize: function() {

         var xScroll, yScroll;

        if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {  
            xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
            yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
        } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
            xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
        } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
            xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }

        var windowWidth, windowHeight;

        if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
            if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
            } else {
                windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
            }
            windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
            windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }   

        // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
        if(yScroll < windowHeight){
            pageHeight = windowHeight;
        } else { 
            pageHeight = yScroll;
        }

        // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
        if(xScroll < windowWidth){  
            pageWidth = xScroll;        
        } else {
            pageWidth = windowWidth;
        }

        return [pageWidth,pageHeight];
    } }

document.observe('dom:loaded', function () { new Lightbox(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731779/make-page-stop-scrolling-when-lightbox-is-active) is as simple as adding overflow: hidden to your body when you show the lightbox and overflow: auto when you hide it.

Comment: Right, no worries and sorry for the delay, your lightbox has a click event that triggers it with Javascript, there you can do it, the line would be something like this `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` then in the close event do it but with auto instead of hidden (if you're using the html approach to trigger the lightbox you'll need to switch to the javascript I mention, you gotta check the docs of the particular library you're using to know how to go about that, they're usually pretty well explained.