# Overlay Scrolling Issue

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating an overlay for a page and for some reason every time I scroll (vertically) the overlay scrolls the background instead of scrolling the actual overlay.

[image]

I am following the code in the following link: 
[Prevent body scrolling but allow overlay scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling)

But when I apply no scroll to the body class then everything on the page stops scrolling even the overlay.

Comment: Could you link to an example of your issue?
[codepen](http://codepen.io/) or  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would do nicely.

Comment: I wish I could paste the code! There is too much code to paste.

Comment: Code testing 101: Make a reduced case scenario and test that. Otherwise there is likely to be too much code to test against.

Comment: added the update which indicates the link I am following.

Comment: Is this not then a duplicate of the linked issue?