# Why is the scroll event not working in my div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have an `html` with `body`'s `height` and `width` properties set to `100%`, and a large `viewport` `div` for scrolling.

I want to catch the event in both desktop and mobile browsers.

But now, it's not working, when the `viewport` `div` is scrolling.

```js
;
(function() {
  var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');

  function test() {
    console.log("aaa");
  }

  viewport.addEventListener('scroll', test, false);
  //nothing happen here

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

  }, false);

})();
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

#viewport {
  width: 12222px;
  height: 5000px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 35px, rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 70px);
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#info {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


</head>

<body>

  <p id="info">text</p>
  <div id="viewport">
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you need to add some content into  `box` ..like some text or something.

Comment: @David Is this relationship with the event problem? XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because `scroll` event fired on body, not on your '.viewport' element. Try

```
;
(function() {
var viewport = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

function test() {
  console.log("aaa");
}

viewport.addEventListener('scroll', test, false);
//nothing happen here

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

}, false);

})();
```

Comment: seems working now! but why the event fired on body not on `viewport`?

Comment: because block `.viewport` will be firing `scroll` only when it's content will have larger height then viewport height. And also may be needed to set for the viewport CSS property `overflow-y:scroll` or `overflow-y:auto`

Answer (score 1):

The scroll event always gets fired on the body element until you set the body non-scrollable with style:"overflow: hidden". Then make a div or section of the page scrollable. For reference use this link which explains all the details: [Prevent body scrolling but allow overlay scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling)