# Prevent scrolling above a fixed element

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I've a full page fixed element to show 'This page is loading' gif image. But the page has contents which overflows the body. And user can scroll it over this fixed element. Is there a CSS way I can prevent this? I could have catch the event and stop it through JS. But a clean CSS way would be great.

```
.page-loading {
  background: rgba($white, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 14;

  &__image {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

I've refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling). But I want to control it from the component itself.(without JS)

Comment: Can you add a sample code showing your problem ?

Comment: Here's a video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h_fjEDDwlc. As you can see you can scroll through that fixed element.

Answer (score 1):

As in the link you already provided, you have to apply `overflow:hidden;` to your body.