# Body Images show on top of overlay

Tags: html, css

I've used technique described by fcalderan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling/21958711) to prevent body scrolling, but allow overlay scrolling.

I've used first method which "works by changing the aria-hidden attribute of the overlay in order to show and hide it and to increase its accessibility."

It works, however some of the body images are appearing on top of overlay(overlay is not working completely). Can't figure our what's the problem. Could you please help?

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrrxML). I've included practically all page cause I don't know here the problem is. (Also on codepen the body background is still scrolling, but on local host it's working correctly)

To trigger pop-up click "POP-UP TRIGGER BLOCK"

**CSS**

```
.noscroll { 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay { 
   position: fixed; 
   overflow-y: scroll;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }

[aria-hidden="true"]  { display: none; }
[aria-hidden="false"] { display: block; }
```

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](https://puu.sh/xP7y6/b5f2d687a4.png) of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `z-index` *property* with some high enough *value* to the `.overlay` div, e.g.:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```