# Getting rid of body page scrolling when modal is open

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the class `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` tag with javascript to hide the scroll but it is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

I am getting the element by tag name:
`var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");`

Then after the modal is fired I want to add the class `.no-scrolling { overflow: hidden; }` to the body tag.

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("finance-modal")[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("finance-modal-btn")[0];
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("finance-modal-close")[0];
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  body.classList.add("no-scrolling");
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

And, it is not working!

This is my **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyzefn03/65/)**.

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling#9280412

Comment: It doesn't solve your question but I believe you need document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

Answer (score 4):

This might not work `var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");`. Try `var body = document.body;` instead.

As for removing scrolling you need to set `{overflow-y: hidden;}`

Answer (score 0):

Done!

`var body = document.querySelector("body");` did it.

It would be then:

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("finance-modal")[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("finance-modal-btn")[0];
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("finance-modal-close")[0];
var body = document.querySelector("body");

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    body.classList.add("no-scrolling");
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    body.classList.remove("no-scrolling");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        body.classList.remove("no-scrolling");
    }
}
```