# How to show Full Lightbox Image on Full and Small Height Browsers?

Tags: html, css, sass, lightbox

Hello Im trying to show off my potfolio using lightbox. Right now when the browser height is full you can see the entire image along with paragraph and buttons.

[image]

The problem is when the browser height is smaller you get two scroll bars (I only want one) and you cant scroll down and see the buttons. Im worried people with a smaller laptop wont be able to see the buttons.

[image]

So this are the two things I need help with

1. How to have only one scroll bar?
2. how to set up the scroll bar to scr

HTML

```
    <!-- ================= Image & Lightbox Container ================== -->

    <!-- PHOTO BOOTH TEMPLATE KING -->

    <div class="single-content webdesign webdev grid-item">
      <a href="#img21">
        <img
          class="p2"
          src="http://ruben123.com/img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/web-design/Photo-booth-template-king_Web-Design_01.jpg"
        />
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->

    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img21">
      <div class="image-button-container bg-white p-2">
        <img
          src="http://ruben123.com/img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/web-design/Lightbox/Photo-booth-template-king_Web-Design-light-box_01.jpg"
        />
        <div class="button-text-container">
          <p class="py-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
            temporibus suscipit magni deleniti accusamus fuga dolores et
            dignissimos quo, odio officia nihil dicta maiores eos ut nobis
            id iure facere.
          </p>

          <!-- ======================== ****** Buttons Container ****** ======================== -->
          <div class="buttons-container">
            <!-- Button Download -->
            <form
              method="get"
              action="img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/downloads/PBT-King-Web-Design.zip"
            >
              <button class="btn-dark" type="submit">Download PSD</button>
            </form>

            <!-- Visit Website -->
            <button
              class="btn-dark"
              onclick="window.location.href = 'https://photoboothtemplateking.com/';"
            >
              Visit Website
            </button>
          </div>
          <!-- ======================== ****** Buttons Container ****** ======================== -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- ================= ******************* IMAGE & LIGHTBOX CONTAINER - END ******************* ================== -->
```

SCSS

```
/** LIGHTBOX WEBSITE MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
  /** Default lightbox to hidden */
  display: none;

  /** Position and style */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
  /** Pad the lightbox image */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  // margin-top: 2%;
}

.image-button-container {
  // position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.lightbox .button-text-container {
  p {
    // width: 40%;
    // color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .buttons-container {
    // position: absolute;
    // bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    // display: block;
    // position: relative;

    .btn-dark {
      margin: 0 1rem;
      border: 3px solid white;
    }
  }
}

.lightbox:target {
  /** Remove default browser outline */
  outline: none;

  /** Unhide lightbox **/
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.lightbox {
  /** Default lightbox to hidden */
  display: none;

  /** Position and style */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
  /** Pad the lightbox image */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  // margin-top: 2%;
}

.image-button-container {
  // position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
}

.lightbox .button-text-container {
  p {
    // width: 40%;
    // color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .buttons-container {
    // position: absolute;
    // bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    // display: block;
    // position: relative;

    .btn-dark {
      margin: 0 1rem;
      border: 3px solid white;
    }
  }
}

.lightbox:target {
  /** Remove default browser outline */
  outline: none;

  /** Unhide lightbox **/
  display: block;
}
.p2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container portfolio">
    <div class="single-content webdesign webdev grid-item">
      <a href="#img21">
        <img
          class="p2"
          src="http://ruben123.com/img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/web-design/Photo-booth-template-king_Web-Design_01.jpg"
        >
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->

    <a id="img21" href="#_" class="lightbox">
      <div class="image-button-container bg-white p-2">
        <img
          src="http://ruben123.com/img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/web-design/Lightbox/Photo-booth-template-king_Web-Design-light-box_01.jpg"
        >
        <div class="button-text-container">
          <p class="py-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
            temporibus suscipit magni deleniti accusamus fuga dolores et
            dignissimos quo, odio officia nihil dicta maiores eos ut nobis
            id iure facere.
          </p>

          <!-- ======================== ****** Buttons Container ****** ======================== -->
          <div class="buttons-container">
            <!-- Button Download -->
            <form
              method="get"
              action="img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/downloads/PBT-King-Web-Design.zip"
            >
              <button class="btn-dark" type="submit">Download PSD</button>
            </form>

            <!-- Visit Website -->
            <button
              class="btn-dark"
              onclick="window.location.href = 'https://photoboothtemplateking.com/';"
            >
              Visit Website
            </button>
          </div>
          <!-- ======================== ****** Buttons Container ****** ======================== -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

To prevent body scrolling, here's my reference. [Prevent body from scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling)

You forgot to set the width of the image to 100% and I've set the max height to 90vh and used flex to align it to center.

I hope this will help you.