# Weird scrolling behaviour with overflowing div

Tags: html, css

I've got the following sample code:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" tabindex="0">
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet capicola pig ribeye andouille. Brisket chuck ham biltong frankfurter landjaeger cupim kielbasa prosciutto. Capicola kevin chuck salami bacon. Shank t-bone strip steak shoulder tri-tip tenderloin turducken rump pork loin andouille
    fatback bacon chicken shankle ground round.</p>

  <p>Brisket turducken beef ribs picanha shank ribeye shoulder, pig rump strip steak. Prosciutto tri-tip strip steak pork, swine pork chop sausage meatloaf cupim pancetta. Venison jowl sirloin pig cow, short ribs strip steak rump shankle meatball. Corned
    beef meatloaf short loin pork belly meatball swine, ham pancetta andouille sausage. Fatback short loin turducken pork loin, shank porchetta salami pork belly leberkas shankle picanha tenderloin doner ball tip. Spare ribs pastrami cow capicola sausage
    jowl shank ball tip kevin ham chuck short loin.</p>

  <p>Ground round sausage filet mignon pastrami shank. Tenderloin t-bone drumstick ground round, bresaola rump pork chop alcatra kevin turducken turkey. Corned beef flank picanha beef chicken. Pork loin pastrami short loin meatball chicken sausage alcatra
    andouille venison.</p>

  <p>Turkey alcatra pancetta spare ribs boudin filet mignon venison ball tip salami drumstick. Flank pastrami ball tip prosciutto bresaola, tenderloin beef ribs fatback beef brisket strip steak chicken biltong. Ham boudin pancetta, corned beef rump salami
    chicken drumstick. Picanha cow flank swine fatback, hamburger frankfurter shank meatloaf ham hock. Pastrami pancetta prosciutto shoulder. Filet mignon sausage jowl biltong tail pork turkey boudin tongue short loin meatball flank pork belly.</p>
</div>
```

When scrolling in the div with the text in it, sometimes the body div seems to scroll too. If I scroll quickly to the top of the div with the text in it, it seems to happen with regular occurrence.

How to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Once you reach the end of div in any direction, the scroll would scroll the page instead, natural behaviour

Comment: How can I turn this off? I don't like it at all.

Comment: Complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling with your definition of overflow hidden on the body/html, this may prevent things from showing up, but should be ok if applied only when modal shows

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to hide the overflow on the `html` element as well. Especially for ios/apple devices, I think the overscroll thing happens on the `html` element (can't test right now).

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```