# Scroll in selectyze plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery plugin selectyze (https://github.com/alpixel/Selectyze) that replace the standard selectbox (dropdown) there is a smal "problem" thats kinda irritating and I hope somebody maybe have a solution.

**Problem**

When expand the list and then place the pointer to a option and scroll the list scroll to the bottom, then when continue scrolling the page start to scroll also.

**Example**

http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/selectyze/

Expand a select-menu then scroll.

**Code**

https://github.com/alpixel/Selectyze

I hope anybody maybe know what to edit to make the scroll of page stop when scroll in the selectbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090055/669677) and extending the Selectyze js events.

Lets try it:

http://jsbin.com/ododut/5/

Comment: Thats look like a solution! Thanks for your time. I hope I get it to work, accept your answer soon if its working. Thanks again.

Comment: The bad thing about this solution was that it hides the body scroll, makes the whole page move when scrollbar hide/show. I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10514680/1905754 but I cant really get it to work. Hope somebody have a similar solution to the selectyze plugin.