# Prevent parent scroll when in child div

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

When I scroll to the bottom of the child `div`, the `body` element starts scrolling.

How can I prevent this? I only want the `body` to scroll when the cursor is over it.

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mmay/)

Comment: I edited the question, if the requirements are incorrect, please roll back. As far as I am aware, this is the default browser behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling child div scrolls the window, how do I stop that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211203/scrolling-child-div-scrolls-the-window-how-do-i-stop-that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By adding some javascript of course!

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5mmay/1/)**

```
$( '.area' ).on( 'mousewheel', function ( e ) {
    var event = e.originalEvent,
        d = event.wheelDelta || -event.detail;

    this.scrollTop += ( d < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why * 30? Can you please elaborate? It works, but how?

Comment: 30 is the number of pixels you scroll with each tick of the mousewheel. It is multiplied by -1 (to move backwards) if the original delta was negative.

Comment: Instead of only preventing parent scrolling this completely hijacks scroll and adds it's own scroll logic which isn't cross compatible and not very good.

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer seems outdated. The ["mousewheel"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) event is a non-standard feature. The "[wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)" event seems to be the standard now. Also wheelDelta isn't defined in most browsers. Change to -event.deltaY seems to do the trick. Works in IE 10, Chrome and Firefox

```
$(".scroll-div").on("wheel", function ( e ) {
            var event = e.originalEvent,
                d = -event.deltaY || -event.detail ;

            this.scrollTop += ( d < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I am not getting `e.originalEvent` in Javascript(not using jQuery). Can I directly use `e.deltaY` and `e.detail`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not nesting your elements inside other scrolling elements (most cases) you can take this simple high performance approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.self-scroll').on('mouseover', function () {
    document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
  });
  $('.self-scroll').on('mouseout', function () {
    document.body.style.overflow='auto'; // or = 'visible'
  });
});
```

Now if you apply `self-scroll` class to any element, it will not scroll body.

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/

It fully addresses the issue of locking mouse wheel scroll inside a given container, preventing it from propagating to parent element.

It does not change wheel scrolling speed, user experience will not be affected. and you get the same behavior regardless of the OS mouse wheel vertical scrolling speed (On Windows it can be set to one screen or one line up to 100 lines per notch).

Demo: http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/example/

Source: https://github.com/MohammadYounes/jquery-scrollLock

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$(document).ready(function() {


// to prevent scrolling of parent div when modal is open
var $window = $(window);
var $body = $(window.document.body);

window.onscroll = function() {
        var overlay = $body.children(".ui-widget-overlay").first();
        // Check if the overlay is visible and restore the previous scroll state
        if (overlay.is(":visible")) {
        var scrollPos = $body.data("scroll-pos") || { x: 0, y: 0 };
        window.scrollTo(scrollPos.x, scrollPos.y);
    }
    else {
        // Just store the scroll state
        $body.data("scroll-pos", { x: $window.scrollLeft(), y: $window.scrollTop() });
    }
};
```

});

it will lock scrolling on parent window. Worked for me