# Cancel wheel event with e.preventDefault in react event bubbling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, scrollbar, mousewheel

I am trying to prevent window scrolling with `e.preventDefault()` when a wheel event is fired but browser scrolls no matter what.

```
<div onWheel={this.handleWheelEvent} >
  <div className='yellow fullpage'>Yellow Page</div>
  <div className='green fullpage'>Green Page</div>
  <div className='blue fullpage'>Yellow Page</div>
</div>
```

js

```
handleWheelEvent = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // those 3 should prevent browser from scrolling but they don't
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was ReactJS not JS. This link should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790949/react-js-onwheel-bubbling-stoppropagation-not-working

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find a way to prevent scrolling in React events but it's possible to achieve same effect using refs

In constructor:

```
this.divRef = React.createRef()
this.preventDefault = e => e.preventDefault()
```

In render:

```
<div ref={this.divRef} >
  <div className='yellow fullpage'>Yellow Page</div>
  <div className='green fullpage'>Green Page</div>
  <div className='blue fullpage'>Yellow Page</div>
</div>
```

Adding and removing preventDefault event listener:

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.divRef.current.addEventListener('wheel', this.preventDefault)
}

componentWillUnmount () {
    this.divRef.current.removeEventListener('wheel', this.preventDefault)
}
```

Comment: this is the only method that worked for me after testing many other solutions, mostly that utilize blur(). thanks!

Answer (score 5):

React binds all events at the root element (not the `document`), and the `wheel` event is binded internally using `true` [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters), and I quote MDN:

> *A Boolean that, if true, indicates that the function specified by listener will never call preventDefault(). If a passive listener does call preventDefault(), the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning*

This is how I did blocked the page from scrolling while using the wheel to affect an input field:

```js
const wheelTimeout = useRef()

const onWheel = e => {
    // ... some code I needed ...

    // while wheel is moving, do not release the lock
    clearTimeout(wheelTimeout.current)

    // flag indicating to lock page scrolling (setTimeout returns a number)
    wheelTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      wheelTimeout.current = false
    }, 300)
}

// block the body from scrolling (or any other element)
useEffect(() => {
    const cancelWheel = e => wheelTimeout.current && e.preventDefault()
    document.body.addEventListener('wheel', cancelWheel, {passive:false})
    return () => document.body.removeEventListener('wheel', cancelWheel)
}, [])
```

---

Reference discussions:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14856

Comment: Excellent answer and reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use ‍`event.preventDefault()` inside event onScroll, because preventDefault apply after page scrolled. But you can use prevetDefault on the following events:

- onWheel
- onKeydown
- onPageUp
- onPageDown

Answer (score -3):

```
<div onWheel={e => e.stopPropagation()}></div>
```

try this