# React useState hook attached to an Input type number not updating value on mouse scroll

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying a simple use-case where a value of an input type number should change using a mouse scroll. It is working when I used useState hook to the input. Value is not updating, instead, the page is scrolling. Don't know what is missing.

Please see the example block of code

```
import React from 'react'

const NumberField = () =>{

   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState()
 
   const handleInputChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
       const value = event.target.value
       setInputValue(value)
   }

   return(
       <input type="number" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange}>
   )
}
```

Can anyone please provide a solution to update the value on scroll and at the same time page should not scroll when the value is updating in the input field. Thanks.

Comment: You want the input value to change when scrolling the page?

Comment: Not when scrolling the page but, when I click on the input field and then scroll. Just like the normal input type number field https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onWheel event [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#wheel-events).

Handle Wheel Scroll function

```
const handleWheelScroll = (event:React.WheelEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    if(event.deltaY > 0){
        setInputValue(inputValue - 1);
    }else{
        setInputValue(inputValue + 1);
    }
}
```

Or in short

```
const handleWheelScroll = (event:React.WheelEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setInputValue(inputValue + (event.deltaY > 0 ? -1 : 1));
}
```

Than in your render

```
<input onWheel={handleWheelScroll} type="number" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34147719/7645069 for up and down checking code

Comment: Thanks for the answer value is changing on scroll but, the problem is even the page is scrolling. How to stop the page from scrolling?

Comment: Hmm event.stopPropagation should work not sure why it's not doing the job...

Comment: @praveenguda does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790949/react-js-onwheel-bubbling-stoppropagation-not-working