# Sidebar scroll connected to main container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a layout build on flexboxes.
In the fixed sidebar I have scroll as well as in the main container.
The issue is that while I'm scrolling in a sidebar and reaching the end of the scroll, the scroll from the main container starts to scroll. How to prevent that and scroll only what user has focused on (only sidebar or main container)?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling child div scrolls the window, how do I stop that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211203/scrolling-child-div-scrolls-the-window-how-do-i-stop-that)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden';" onmouseout="document.body.style.overflow='auto';"></div>
```

from

[Scrolling child div scrolls the window, how do I stop that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211203/scrolling-child-div-scrolls-the-window-how-do-i-stop-that)