# "Hook up" Browser Scrollbar to only a single HTML Element

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, scrollbar

I want everything in my page to stay put when I scroll except for just one specified element.

How do I magically "hook up" one HTML element to the browser's default scrollbar so that it affects only that one element in my entire HTML document? ... **Without using the position:fixed property**?

I only need to support Chrome.

I know I'm dreaming crazy, but I'm hoping a CSS/JavaScript/HTML wizard can calm me down a bit with some zany contraption.

Comment: Take a look at this question, I think it might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399826/hook-up-browser-scrollbar-to-only-a-single-html-element

Comment: Well, that is **exactly** my question :)  It's also unanswered!

Comment: So sorry, I pasted the wrong url, try with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887112/scroll-particular-div-contents-with-browsers-main-scrollbar