# trying to get scrolling div not to affect another div on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, mobile

So here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a id="x" href="#" style="position:fixed; top:0; right:10px;">Switch</a>
    <div id="a">
        <p>Huge paragraph 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="b" style="display:none;">
        <p>Huge paragraph 2</p>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#x').click(function() {
            $('#a').toggle();
            $('#b').toggle();

            return false;
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that let's say I've scrolled midway thru paragraph 1, and then hit the switch link.  So now I'm looking at paragraph 2.  Let's say I do some scrolling on paragraph 2, then decide I want to switch back to paragraph 1, so I hit switch.  Problem is that when I switch back to paragraph 1, I'm in a completely different spot then my original midway point.  How can I get each div's scrolling to basically only scroll their own respective content so that if I were to switch I can still continue where I left off previously?

Comment: From my experience, scrolling divs on mobile devices don't seem to work very well (Some ignore the `overflow:scroll` and don't even let the div scroll.) To scroll a div on a mobile device, I've used http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4.

Comment: Can you think of any solutions that won't involve plugins? :)

Answer (score 1):

The key is to store the scrollTop on the body element just before you toggle your elements.

Once you have stored that value, simply set it again each time.

Heres a quick and dirty implementation: http://jsbin.com/efijey/1/edit

Comment: I thought of this too, but was hoping there was a more elegant way just using CSS. Apparently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887112 solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my question.

[Update anchor tag as you scroll past an element in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187633/update-anchor-tag-as-you-scroll-past-an-element-in-a-div/13187674#comment17950864_13187674)

And someone answered with this for the response which works perfect. You could make it so each spot on each div is saved and have it switch with the switch button.

http://jsbin.com/ezexaf/1/edit

Comment: Is this just a guess or does it actually work on your phone?  I'm asking because this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Check my update! I asked a similar question and this should help you because it is exactly what you are asking for.