# Update anchor tag as you scroll past an element in a div

Tags: javascript, anchor, getelementbyid

I am not sure if this is possible that is why I am on here asking so if you have any ideas on how this would be possible then I would greatly appreciate it!

Ok say that I have a div that scrolls with overflow-y feature. And say that inside of this div there is a story or large amount of text. Is there anyway to have Javascript memorize or save where you are at in this div maybe through a line number or anchor tag possibly? That way whenever the div is gone, such as if I had javascript change the content of the div, I can prompt the user to click a button and it will return to the spot they were originally at?

I have no approach at this at all! :( The farthest I can think is the simple way of giving each line an anchor tag which is very repetitive and not worth the time and I still wouldn't know how to get the anchor tag on scroll over.

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;"> 

<span id="1">This would</span>

<span id="2">be too</span>

<span id="3"> repetitive and</span>

<span id="4">still dont know</span>

<span id="4">how to save the anchor</span>

 </div>
```

I was thinking for the javascript maybe something like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('***CURRENTSPOT***').id = 'spot';">Save Spot</a>
```

Then to reload all they would have to do is click this

```
<a href="#spot">Load Saved Spot</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving the scrollTop property of the parent DOM element and setting that again when the user loads the saved spot.

Check out [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop) for more details

Heres a quick and dirty implementation: http://jsbin.com/ezexaf/1/edit

Comment: That would give me the number of pixels scrolled...but how would I return that value in a way to scroll back to that spot in the div?

Comment: You can also set the scrollTop property back to the same element.

Comment: I have never even heard of this javascript before and I'm not even sure how to implement it...can you show me an example of its code in your answer?

Comment: Sure i've updated my answer with something rough and dirty. Hope it helps you.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much...that is much easier than what I was trying.