# Only scrolling in the menu items, not in the content of the html page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing a stiky menu where in **mobile devices** the menu items become scrollables. The problem is, when I reach the end of the menu, I start scrolling the main content. How can I avoid that and how I avoid bouncing efect at the end in safari for iPhone devices?

example:

```js
(function() {
  var that = this;
  var navOffset, nav;

  that.init = function() {
    nav = jQuery('#nav-bar');
    if (!nav)
      return;
    navOffset = nav.offset().top;

    jQuery(window).scroll(that.addStickyMenu);
    jQuery(window).resize(that.addStickyMenu);

  };

  that.addStickyMenu = function() {
    var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > navOffset) {
      nav.addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      nav.removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    that.init();
  });
})();
```

```css
#nav-bar {
  height: 45px;
  background: #0d3349;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100%
}
.nav-container {
  max-height: 667px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="nav-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="nav-container">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Navbar example</h1>
      <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words.
      Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the
      grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages.</p>

    <p>It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family.
      Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be
      desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words.</p>

    <p>If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple
      as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate
      existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words.</p>

    <p>Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the
      grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will
      be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth.</p>

    <p>For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive
      translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages.
      The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.</p>

    <p>To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
      Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve
      this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language
      will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages.</p>

    <p>It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family.
      Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be
      desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and
      regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like
      simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The
      languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why</p>

    <p>The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words.
      Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the
      grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages.</p>

    <p>It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family.
      Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be
      desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words.</p>

    <p>If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple
      as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate
      existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words.</p>

    <p>Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the
      grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will
      be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth.</p>

    <p>For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive
      translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages.
      The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.</p>

    <p>To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc,
      Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve
      this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language
      will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages.</p>

    <p>It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family.
      Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be
      desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and
      regular than that of the individual languages. The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental. To an English person, it will seem like
      simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The
      languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why</p>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>

  <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

/**https://jsfiddle.net/b46wmmhe/**/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll particular DIV contents with browser's main scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887112/scroll-particular-div-contents-with-browsers-main-scrollbar)

Comment: If you want to disable scrolling in the main content area when you reach the bottom of the sticky menu you can't have the sticky menu be a child of the main content div. See the duplicate question I posted and this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/qndjW/11/

Comment: why you add the jquery ??